# Tkinter: How can I provide text status updates during execution that is in response to a single event?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

I have **primary.py**, the primary file of a Tkinter app that has a user select a file, and then calls a variety of functions contained in **other.py**.

The functions in **other.py** take a while to run, so I want to provide users with updates after each one is complete.

My issue is that all of these messages appear all at once, after the completion of step 3. I want them to appear after each step, as I tried to write it. How can I ensure 'Step 1 in Progress' appears before `dummy2` is called, and not at the end of all the functions being performed?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import ttk
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import other.py

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

def tkinter_display(the_message):
    ttk.Label(frame, text=the_message, style='my.TLabel').pack()

def select():

    path = askopenfilename()

    tkinter_display('The script is running...')

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        side1, side2 = Pipe()

        tkinter_functions_conn.send(path)

        p_import = Process(target=other.dummy, args=(side2,))
        p_import.start()

        tkinter_display('Step 1 in progress')
        tkinter_display(side1.recv())

        p_import2 = Process(target=other.dummy2, args=(side2,))
        p_import2.start()

        tkinter_display('Step 2 in progress')

        p_import3 = Process(target=other.dummy3, args=(side2,))
        p_import3.start()

        tkinter_display('Step 3 in progress')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk() 
    my_gui = GUI(root)

    # Styles
    root.style = ttk.Style()
    root.style.configure('my.TButton')
    root.style.configure('my.TLabel')

    # Display
    frame = Frame()
    frame.pack()

    ttk.Button(frame, text="Select", command=select, style='my.TButton').pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try putting some `root.update_idletasks()` calls into your `select` function. It might help...

Comment: Came here with the same issue, update_idletasks() worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the GUI to update by changing your `tkinter_display` method to this:

```
def tkinter_display(the_message):
    ttk.Label(frame, text=the_message, style='my.TLabel').pack()
    frame.update()
```